# New computer and fresh git clone giving 500+ errors, don't know what I'm missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, reactiveui

I have a WPF application (using ReactiveUI for MVVM) created in Visual Studio 2019 v16.7~. It is stored in Azure DevOps git repo.

**OS**
Windows 10 Pro Ver 1909

**Visual Studio 2019 Workloads for installation**
ASP.NET and web development
.Net desktop development
.Net Core cross-platform development

**.Net**
Installed .Net Core 3.1 SDK
Installed .Net Framework 4.8

**Project Types in solution:**
WPF - .Net Framework 4.8
Library1  - .Net Standard 2.0
Web API - .Net Core 3.1

**User story:**
My computer died several days ago and had to get a new one.

- I installed the latest Visual Stduio 2019 v16.8 (previous version was 16.7).
- I installed all my extension tools
- I cloned my solution
- The project opens fine.
  However, it has 578 errors (few errors shown below).

I noticed the Target framework is blank and disabled on a few of the projects, which include .Net Core 3.1 and .Net Standard 2 projects (see image below).

Here's what I tried:
I created a new console project with a .Net Standard 2 library and I get errors off the bat (see image below).

What am I missing?

Here are a few of the errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1202  Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions 2.2.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions 2.2.0 does not support any target frameworks.    


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1202  Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.1.8 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.1.8 does not support any target frameworks.    

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1202  Package AutoMapper 10.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package AutoMapper 10.0.0 does not support any target frameworks.
```

[image]

[image]

**Update:**
Tried to do a repair on Visual Studio...

[image]

Comment: Open Solution Explorer and see under References if any are yellow.

Comment: See updated OP at bottom for new image.

Comment: Check in Control Panel the installed software and see what version of Net are installed.  You may have more than one version of Net.  You can also try from menu Project : Add Reference : Net and select the missing references.  I would thing the using statements at top of module would have errors.

Comment: I have to have 2015, 2017 and 2019 installed and I installed it in that order. This was how my old computer was setup as well.

Comment: I did ask about VS.  I said Net!!!

Comment: Each version of VS installs a different version of Net. So I think you did not install the Net version for 2019 which is Net 16.3.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-visual-studio?view=vs-2019